# gwt 18n properties files

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, uibinder

i have LocalizableResource_lang.properties located at 
com.google.gwt.client . using uibinder  `<ui.msg:` i able to get the 
i18n messages.  let say i programmatically creating widget. and 
created interface   LocalizableResource extends Message  in order to 
read in 18n messages. Is this correct proper way to do it?

Comment: What's your question? Please edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your interface that extends from `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages`, and add your various MyMessages_(en_US|fr_CA).properties files in the same folder.  Use `GWT.create(MyMessages.class)` to create the instance.

See [i18n dev guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html) for more details.